# How to create a SQL statement to produce nested JSON from variables?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, for-json

I have managed to create SQL for the individual nodes, but cannot deduce how to refine the statement to include or merge both outputs.

```
DECLARE
  @FulfillmentOrderId BIGINT = 0,    
  @NotifyCustomer BIT = 1,
  @TrackingCompany NVARCHAR(100) = '',
  @TrackingNo NVARCHAR(100) = '';
```

**INPUT**

```
SELECT            
  @NotifyCustomer AS [notify_customer],
  @TrackingCompany AS [tracking_info.company],
  @TrackingNo AS [tracking_info.number]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  "line_items_by_fulfillment_order": [
    {
      "fulfillment_order_id": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**INPUT**

```
SELECT (
  SELECT
    @FulfillmentOrderId AS [fulfillment_order_id]
  FOR JSON PATH
) AS [line_items_by_fulfillment_order]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  "notify_customer": true,
  "tracking_info": {
    "company": "",
    "number": ""
  }
}
```

---

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
{
  "fulfillment": {
    "notify_customer": true,
    "tracking_info": {
      "company": "",
      "number": 0
    },
    "line_items_by_fulfillment_order": [
      {
        "fulfillment_order_id": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the nested `"line_items_by_fulfillment_order"` JSON array and change the paths:

```
SELECT            
   @NotifyCustomer AS [fulfillment.notify_customer],
   @TrackingCompany AS [fulfillment.tracking_info.company],
   @TrackingNo AS [fulfillment.tracking_info.number],
   (SELECT @FulfillmentOrderId AS fulfillment_order_id FOR JSON PATH) AS [fulfillment.line_items_by_fulfillment_order]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

SQL Server 2022 introduced new JSON features, so the following statement is also an option:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
   'fulfillment': JSON_OBJECT(
       'notify_customer': @NotifyCustomer, 
       'tracking_info': JSON_OBJECT('company': @TrackingCompany, 'number': @TrackingNo),
       'line_items_by_fulfillment_order': JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('fulfillment_order_id': @FulfillmentOrderId))
   )  
)
```

Result:

```
{
"fulfillment":{
    "notify_customer":true,
    "tracking_info":{"company":"","number":""},
    "line_items_by_fulfillment_order":[{"fulfillment_order_id":0}]
}
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I was blind to it. Thanks for the clarification.